# Firebase Authentication does not work properly

Tags: firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have an activity to check my user's mail id is verified or not ie, when a user register to my app goes to an activity to verify mail id. Also, when user signed in to my app, user goes to mailVerify activity if user not verified his mail. Otherwise goes to home activity.
I implemented the code as this,

```
If(mAuth.getCurrentUser!=null)
{
 if(mAuth.getCurrentUser
.isEmailVerified)
{
finish();
startActivity(new
Intent(SignInActivity.this,
MailVerify.class));
else{
startActivity(new
Intent(SignInActivity.this,
UserHome.class ));
}
}
}
```

My Problem is whenever I signed into my app and goes to email and verify it, after this when clicking on signin button it still stands on Mailverify activity. How to fix this problem guys?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your firebase database.

It is read / write access or not.

Comment: it only works at the time of clear the data of application and sign in to the app.It does not work for newly reghistered time.It only works when i clear data of application

Answer (score 0):

First way:
Go to your firebase console and check the rules of your database auth:
In order to do this:
First go to your Database:
[First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKEH9.jpg)

Second check your rules they should be such:
[Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dauTS.jpg)

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

After checking please inform me about this.

Comment: it only works at the time of clear the data of application and sign in to the app.It does not work for newly reghistered time.It only works when i clear data of application